# How to feed env variables through Docker compose and serve React app in NGINX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a React app. In the app there's a `.env` file and in the file there's an environment variable named `REACT_APP_SIZE`. I'm reading the the env variables using `process.env` and exporting it using a `config.js` file as shown below.

```
export const SIZE = process.env.REACT_APP_SIZE
```

I'm using the above exported SIZE variable where ever I wanted.

I'm using Docker to build the React app and serve it using NGINX and starting the app using a `docker-compose` file. Following is my `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`:

```
FROM node:16 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx:1.21-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:80
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_SIZE=100000000
```

I'm feeding the env variable using Docker compose but the React app doesn't read the value passed through Docker compose. instead it reads the value in the `.env` file.

What I want is to change the env values using Docker compose without building the React app every time.

Comment: You can't do that, CRA's [custom environment variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) are a _build-time_ feature. If you want to reconfigure the app _after_ the build you need an entirely different approach (see e.g. [my blog](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html)).